# SVN: synchronizing branches

Tags: svn

If we have some branch, B1, is there a way to create branch B2 from it so that commits will be synchronizing? I.e., committing into branch B1 also causes updating in B2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course, you can use Subversion [post-commit hooks](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.0/svn-book.html#svn-ch-5-sect-2.1).

Comment: I don't think it's good solution; you can get more troubles with it than benefits

Comment: As far as I understood the task, B2 branch is a simple mirror of B1.

Otherwise, of course, conflicts ensue.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't. You have to merge changes manually. Take a look at svnmerge. This can help to automatize this process.[link](http://progblog.wordpress.com/2007/02/21/automatic-branch-merging-with-svnmerge-on-subversion/)

Answer (score 0):

No. You have to merge the changes yourself.